# Why does block object not dealloc the same way NSObject does?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

Here's a code snippet that illustrates the problem

```
__weak id ptr = nil;
__weak id ptr2 = nil;
@autoreleasepool {
    void (^block)(void) = [^{
        NSLog(@"hahaha");
    } copy];
    block();
    [[(id)block rac_willDeallocSignal] subscribeCompleted:^{
        NSLog(@"block will dealloc");
    }];
    ptr = block;
    int blockRetainCount = CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)block);

    NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    [obj.rac_willDeallocSignal subscribeCompleted:^{
        NSLog(@"Obj dealloc");
    }];
    ptr2 = obj;
    int objRetainCount = CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)obj);
    NSLog(@"oK");
}
NSLog(@"after pool %@ %@" , ptr, ptr2);
```

When I run this snippet, I will see `Obj dealloc` printed to the console but not `block will dealloc`. After the autorelease pool also I will see `ptr` still containing a valid refence to the block while `ptr2` has been correctly reset to nil as expected. Why is there this difference? When do blocks get dealloc'ed at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple problems that should convince you to not ever try such a thing:

One, CFGetRetainCount isn't guaranteed to return anything meaningful in the presence of ARC.

Two, there is no guarantee that a block uses retain counts at all. Blocks that don't capture any variables are allocated as static variables; copy, retain and so on do nothing at all to them, and they are never allocated or deallocated.

Third, there is no guarantee that any block will ever call dealloc when it is deallocated. And no guarantee that it will happen in the next OS or iOS version.

Comment: I think the key phrase for me is that `Blocks that don't capture any variables are allocated as static variables; copy, retain and so on do nothing at all to them, and they are never allocated or deallocated.` Gonna test this out.

Comment: Indeed! If I change the block definition to ```
        NSString *mystr = @"hahaha";
        void (^block)(void) = [^{
            NSLog(@"%@", mystr);
        } copy];
``` then `ptr` gets set to `nil` at the end of the autorelease pool. The `CFGetRetainCount` and `dealloc` hooks are simply desperate attempts to understand why block isn't getting deallocated :)

Comment: `CFGetRetainCount()` isn't guaranteed to return anything meaningful ever.